# Getting intValue from Integer, does it make any sense?

Tags: java

I am looking through the code someone wrote a while back and wondering whether I am missing something here

Assuming

```
List<Integer> runUids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and later on as part of a loop

```
int runUID = runUidsAL.get(i).intValue();
```

Is there any reason why `intValue()` needs to be called here?. Don't think it's needed here. Do you?

Comment: It depends upon what JDK version is used.

Comment: What is the type of runUID? is it int or Integer? and what is jdk version?

Comment: @thinksteep it's at least JDK 5 otherwise he wouldn't be able to use generics. Since it's at least JDK 5, autoboxing will also be available.

Comment: @thinksteep , may be he had used java 1.4 for this and hence unboxing it explicitly !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't say so, but I assume that `runUID` is an `int`.

It's not necessary to call `intValue()` explicitly on the `Integer` object returned by `runUidsAL.get(i)`; Java will do this automatically by [auto-unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Comment: But if runUID is an `Integer` this creates a copy rather than assigning the reference value (Which in this case is kinda silly given that `Integer` is immutable, and if the value is between -128 and 127 you're going to get the same reference anyway)

Comment: Oh no - I agree - IMHO the reason for it is to show *intent*. Explicit is always better.  I was just pointing out that there was a slight difference if `runUID` was an `Integer`

Comment: I agree. If runUID was an Integer, it is actually "worst" to call intValue() since java will then create a NEW instance of Integer to wrap the result of intValue() instead of simply adding another reference to the existing Integer instance.

Answer (score 3):

A real situation that I have lived a few minutes ago:

I have a list of Integer objects. Each Integer is the index of an other list whose positions I want to remove.

Then... I was doing that:

```
for (Integer index : positionsToRemoveList) {

   historyRecord.remove(index);
}
```

Java was calling to the next method

```
public boolean remove(Object object);
```

Instead of:

```
public E remove(int location);
```

My "historyRecord" List wasn't  being updated beacuse Java was trying to remove by an Object instead of by position.

The right way is:

```
for (Integer index : positionsToRemoveList) {

   historyRecord.remove(index.intValue());
}
```

And this is my real story : )

Answer (score 2):

It's there because Integer extends Number.

```
Number n = new Integer(5);

int i = n.intValue();
```

That second line may need an int value from n, and may not know if n was instantiated with an Integer or Double.

Answer (score 1):

Java 1.5 and above supports automatic boxing and unboxing, which mans you can assign an `Integer` to an `int` without using `.intValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Integer** is an object, while **int** is a primitive.

intValue() method converts between the **Integer** class to its primitive representation.

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html

Comment: Yes, but the point is that if runUID is an `int` you get the same result without calling `intValue()` because of auto unboxing.

Comment: That's true, but it makes it more clear when reading the code. Consider the code "if (i!=0)" and the code "if (i)". They are both equal, but it's just faster to understand what's going on. As far as performances - auto-unboxing and manual unboxing are the same, it's just easier to read the code.

Comment: As I replied this comment before you deleted it from the other answer, that I agree with. However... that's not what this answer is.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an int to a long, but not an Integer object, for example. On the other hand, the intValue() could give a NullPointerException if the Integer object is null.

Comment: Auto unboxing will throw the same `NullPointerException`. It also will happily auto unbox to a `long`; `Integer i = 5; long l = i;`