# unboxing - how it becomes a better way to explicitly use intValue() compared to unboxing by itself

Tags: java, unboxing

I was reading O'REILLY Java8 pocket guide when I came across this advise about unboxing *[On page 30]*

*Note: For these examples, primitive variables end with a capitalP. This is not the convention.*

The following example shows an acceptable but not recommended use of unboxing

Establish the weight allowance

```
weightLimitP = weightLimitP + weightAllowanceW;
```

It is better to write this expression with the `intValue()` method, as shown here:

```
weightLimitP = weightLimitP + weightAllowanceW.intValue();
```

**Question**: What I would like to know here is why is the second approach a better way? I mean, in what terms is it 'better'. How is it different from unboxing by itself

*Note: The wrapper class in this example is `Integer`*

Comment: Surely the pocket guide said something about why the author thinks it's "better"?

Comment: nope. i'm reading O'REILLY Java 8 pocket guide - page 30

Comment: I'd double-check if I were you. I normally expect better of O'Reilly (even in a pocket guide).

Comment: From Java 5 onward, those two code snippets will generate [exactly the same bytecode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915823/which-is-better-in-terms-of-performance-implicit-auto-unboxing-or-explicit-un). So "better" is purely a matter of style, which is opinion-based. Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331059/getting-intvalue-from-integer-does-it-make-any-sense, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985928/what-is-the-need-of-an-intvalue-method-if-wrappers-use-unboxing

Comment: Only difference is writing style. both the codes are equal in terms of bytecode.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder for the relative links and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two code snippets will generate [exactly the same bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915823/which-is-better-in-terms-of-performance-implicit-auto-unboxing-or-explicit-un). So "better" is purely a matter of style and, thus, opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It compiles to the same code. But it *might* be considered to be better style. Reason: one now can see at one glance that a NullPointerException might be raised or that it is a wrapper class, and a primitive class would be better.

This to the adage that code is read more often than written.